# C - sscanf not ignoring white space

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am reading in a text file and using a comma as a delimiter, the line below does work however when I print out lname it does not ignore the white space after the comma and prints a space before name. How can I adjust the code to ignore white space?

example of text:

Rob, Smith, 4, 12, sometext
Steve, Jones, 41, 286, sometext

```
sscanf(line, "%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d,%s", fname,lname,&num1,&num2,info);
```

Comment: Note that `sscanf(",    ,", ", %[^,],", fname);` will stop the scan and not save anything into `fname`.  IOWs, names must contain some non-white-space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a whitespace character if you want to ignore whitespace:

```
sscanf(line, " %[^,], %[^,], %d, %d, %s", fname, lname, &num1, &num2, info);
```

The space before `%d` and `%s` are not required as they already skip leading whitespace characters. The only format specifiers which does not skip leading whitespace are `%c`, `%[` and `%n`.

Note that a whitespace character in the format string of `*scanf` instructs `scanf` to scan any number of whitespace, including none, until the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: Hey Cool Guy, I want to learn all this things, and I am unable to find good source, can you point me to good source about all this?